# Explanation about the rotation spectrum from cold $\rm Cs_2$ molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, spectroscopy

In the book [Mécanique quantique](https://www.editions.polytechnique.fr/?afficherfiche=4) (Jean Dalibard), there is an example to illustrate the quantification of the $L^2$ squared angular momentum.

This example is extracted from *A. Fioretti et al, Eur. Phys. J. D 5, 389 (1999).* (which I don't have access to).

[image: Rotation spectrum from cold Cs_2 molecules]

If I sum up what it says: this graph shows the number of ions produced by a laser pointing on the cold molecules of $\rm Cs_2$ in function of the frequency of the light.
The height of each peak is proportional to the population of the corresponding rotational level $\ell$.

I'd like to have a better understanding of the setup and results (I am just getting back to quantum mechanics, don't be afraid if I ask basic questions):

- Why do the molecules need to be cold?
- What is the ionization process involved and why does it interfere with the angular momentum?
- What is this *ionic signal* exactly and why is it stronger at those energy levels corresponding to the quantified angular momentum?

Any other information about this (or similar) setup would be much appreciated.